# Does the player embed size of a YouTube video affect bandwith?

Tags: video-streaming

I have added a YouTube embed on my webpage that also streaming live video. Will this YouTube video increase the need for bandwidth on the customer/player side? In short, is the YouTube video slowing down the page load. Also, does the dimension or size of the player affect bandwidth need?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The YouTube player will automatically pick an appropriate video resolution based on the resolution you're displaying it at, and the bandwidth available.

You can use the YouTube Iframe API to "suggest" a video quality, but there's no guarantee it will be followed.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. Let me clarify. I have customers that have low bandwidth. My web page, that they are viewing, automatically loads AND plays specific youtube videos that are videos of lots selling in an auction. If I remove the YouTube videos from the webpage will that make it load faster?

Comment: Thank you for your comment also, I have had a hard time finding an accurate answer. Some people say that it is coming from Youtube servers so it doesnt matter, but when I test it seems that it really speeds up the page load if the YouTube videos are not present.

Comment: Yes, of course, if you're not loading video, you'll have plenty of bandwidth left over for loading the page, as you have seen.